# How to use contextPath in html template

Tags: jquery, html, contextpath

I want to know how to use contextPath in html code.

For example, if I load html code like below dynamically in runtime how to use contextPath?? (It is html template, no jsp)

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/contextPath/folder1/file1.do">menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contextPath/folder2/file2.do">menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contextPath/folder3/file3.do">menu3</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

*After load html, add contextPath on  tag's href attribute using jquery??

please help.